# How to load vue-i18n-loader on @symfony/webpack-encore

Tags: symfony, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I'm using Vue on an symfony 4 application with webpack and with vue-18n working fine.
But I want to put the translations on each [single file component](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/en/sfc.html)

My problem is to load de is to load the [vue-i18n-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader)
I tried to load with may ways ....
Has anyone done this?
Thank you

My webpack file:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
Encore
    .enableVueLoader(function(options) {
        //i tried to load here
    })
    // ...
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
    })
    ////i tried to load here with addLoader
;
//I tried to load here with module.exports
// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: you look at this docs : https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/vuejs.html ?

Comment: yes! I did, I tried to change preLoaders to loaders but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to set options in `enableVueLoader`

```
.enableVueLoader(function(options) {
   options.loaders.i18n = '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With Webpack 4, you need to use this syntax:

```
.addRule({
    resourceQuery: /blockType=i18n/,
    type: 'javascript/auto',
    loader: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader',
})
```

Comment: This worked for me, I guess it is because I have installed vue-loader 15 instead of vue-loader 14.
Maybe it is interesting to note that you need to add this to `webpack.config.js`.